# kmag as snap-application: labeling missing

Tags: lubuntu, snap

I wonder if anyone could help me with the following problem:

I installed **kmag** (screen magnifier) as a *snap* using the command

`sudo  snap install kmag --edge` (see https://snapcraft.io/kmag).

All went well and I got the following installed:

```
kde-frameworks-5  5.47.0          27    stable    kde        -

kmag              master+4796c6e  7     edge      kde        -
```

Kmag does work. However all labeling is missing in the opening window. I get just a few cryptic symbols but no letters whatsoever.
Any ideas as to what can be done about it?

My system: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, 64 bit

Comment: By "labeling is missing in the opening window" are you referring to `File`, `Edit`, `View`, `Settings`, `Help` in the first row and `Stop`, `Zoom in` and `Mouse` in the second row?

Comment: https://www.kde.org/images/screenshots/resized/kmag.png is just like what I see but I'm on Kubuntu 1**8**.04 that has KDE Frameworks version 5.44 whereas the snap is using version 5.47. I wonder if something else is needed on 1**6**.04 that the snap packager hasn't accounted for.

Comment: Hi. Yes, exactly. `File`, `Edit` etc in the 1st row is missing completely. `Stop`, `Zoom in` etc in the 2nd row are also missing (the actual words), but the symbols are there. Surely it has something to to with snap packager missing a bit which is much needed. It´s a shame though, as the main functionality of magnification is working.

Comment: *****UPDATE*****    I finally could solve my problem.  After uninstalling kmag as a snap I installed it via apt. Thus kmag was installed plus libqaccessibilityclient0 ("helper to make writing accessibility tools easier"). This one did the trick.
Now kmag works as it should - with all the labeling.

Comment: Hi! Please post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally could solve my problem.
 After uninstalling kmag as a snap I installed it via apt. Thus **kmag** was installed *plus* **libqaccessibilityclient0** ("helper to make writing accessibility tools easier").
 This one did the trick. Now kmag works as it should - with all the labeling.